# AngularJS and Bootstrap's split button dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angular-ui

Do you know if someone ported Bootstrap's scripts to AngularJS?

I need Bootstrap's [split button dropdown](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns) for my app and I'd really like to avoid pulling jQuery in. I seem to fail to google this out.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Look at this demo : http://jsfiddle.net/guillaumebiton/8muRC/

Only the power of Angular:

```
<div class="btn-group" ng-class='{open: open}'>
    <button class="btn">Action</button>
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-click='open=!open'>
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It only use one variable 'open' which is true or false.

Comment: So easy! o_O I must have been really tired ;) Thanks!

Comment: Yep, this really shows power of declarative AngularJS UIs. But in this particular case there is slightly more as the original Boostrap's version closes dropdown when we click outside dropdown as well. It still could be done in pure AngularJS but a small directive starts to make sense here.

Comment: Nice solution! :)
Eventhough, @pkozlowski.opensource is right about the fact that it doesn't close itself when clicking outside.

Comment: Use `type="button"` attribute in button inside form to prevent form submission

Answer (score 10):

As part of the angular-ui we are working on creating bootstrap's widgets in pure AngularJS (no dependencies on 3rd party JS libs, with only dependency being bootstrap's CSS).

The repository is located here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap

This is very much work in progress but there is the dropdown-toggle directive already: 
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/dropdownToggle/dropdownToggle.js

You could use it like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn dropdown-toggle">
        Actions
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a>Action 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Action 2</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note that this directive operates on the class level so it is enough to add the `dropdown-toggle` class to have it operational!

Once again, this is work in progress (the whole effort started something like 2-3 weeks ago) so bug reports / pull requests are very welcomed!

Comment: This appears to be broken? been doing a bit of research, trying different versions and so forth but to no avail, what's the status of this component?

Comment: Perfect, but for Bootstrap 2.3. The 3.0 is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using this directive which converts angularjs select box into the bootstrap's dropdown: http://jsfiddle.net/M32pj/28/ 
`Sample:

```
<select ng-model="example1" bs-selectbox>
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

`